# Run function for an array of values

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, try-catch

I'm trying to run a couple of functions for an array of values and it's not working. Essentially what I want to do is paste and export a PDF of the range A1:C15 for every cell in Z. I have tried a couple of things and nothing seems to work, the latest code I tried is the following:

```
function GuardarPDF(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var refesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("etiqueta");
  var lista_refes = refesSheet.getRange("Z4:Z" + refesSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lista_refes_ok = lista_refes.filter(([a]) => a);
  
 for (var i = 0; i < lista_refes_ok.length; i++) {
    console.log(lista_refes_ok[i][0]) // Here, you can see the folder ID in the log.
    var refes = lista_refes_ok[i][0];
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < lista_refes_ok.length; i++) {
    console.log(lista_refes_ok[i][0]) // Here, you can see the folder ID in the log.
    var refes = lista_refes_ok[i][0];
    try {
       var referencia2 = refesSheet.getRange("B5").setvalue(refes);
    CreaPDF();
    }}
```

(CreaPDF works fine, I'm having trouble generating the iteration so that a PDF for every row in Z is generated)
Does anybody know where the problem is or how to solve it? Thank you so much in advance!
[image: Here is the spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had a variety of errors, but I think this is what you are looking for:

### Try:

```
function GuardarPDF() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const refesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(`etiqueta`)
  const lista_refes = refesSheet.getRange(`Z4:Z${refesSheet.getLastRow()}`)
                                .getValues()
                                .flat()
                                .filter(cell => cell != ``)
  
  lista_refes.forEach(ref => {
    refesSheet.getRange(`B5`).setValue(ref)
    CreaPDF()
    Utilities.sleep(5000)
  })

}
```

This will get all values listed in `Z4:Z(lastRow)`, then remove any blank cells. For each of the values, it will write the `ref` to cell `B5` (potential error), and run `CreaPDF`.

If you need any further explanation, have any questions, or need modification, please let me know!

**Learn More:**

- [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

Comment: hi! thank you so much! this generated a pdf for 6 out of the 9 rows and then I got this: "Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

Comment: `Code 429` is 'too many responses', let me update with something to slow it down in just a moment.

Comment: @VivianRoberts Updated, this will wait 5 seconds before continuing, if you still receive the error, you will want to extend the time appropriately! I'm not sure exactly how it's creating the PDFs so I can't give you an accurate wait time. The time is in milliseconds FYI.

Comment: hii! this code was running smoothly until yesterday! I tried to run it and got this error: Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id "..." 
I searched for the error and saw that sometimes if you make a copy of the sheets and run it again it works, however i tried doing that and it still didn't work and i got the same error

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const rsh = ss.getSheetByName(`Your Sheet Name`)
  const vs = rsh.getRange(4,26,rsh.getLastRow() - 3).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  vs.forEach(e => {
    rsh.getRange(`B5`).setValue(e);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    CreaPDF()
  });
}
```